# ffmpeg - Unable to record screen and speaker audio at the same time

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, x11, pulseaudio

I'm trying to record my screen and speaker audio with **ffmpeg** but I'm facing various problems.

This is the command I'm using:

```bash
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 60 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f pulse -ac 2 -i alsa_output.pci-0000_2d_00.4.analog-stereo.monitor output.mp4
```

but the output video is really slow and out of sync with the audio.
Moreover, I'm getting these warnings:

```
[x11grab @ 0x563635302480] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[aac @ 0x563635319f40] Queue input is backward in time04.49 bitrate= 466.9kbits/s dup=268 drop=45 speed=1.84x    
[mp4 @ 0x5636353172c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 217669, current: 210387; changing to 217670. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

When recording the screen with alsa source (microphone), the output video has no problems.

How can I solve?

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: @Sergey no unfortunately. I switched to OBS in the end.